# web page with java script not working in firefox

Tags: javascript, html

I am using a map on an image. Inside that map I got onmouseover effects for different areas. Also, I have a script that opens an image thumbnail when that area is clicked. This is the script I'm using: http://britobmarketing.com/thumbnailviewer.js

The problem is it's not working in firefox. Not the onmouseover effect, not the thumbnail script. It's simply not working.

Any recommendations?

I really want to stick with java script and not get into Jquery!

Thanks a lot!

Comment: "map on an image" sounds like an ancient stuff.

Comment: Your code is not formatted (indents and such), and your code dump isn't particularly helpful.  Please limit your question and materials to the parts that are significant.  A JSFiddle example would help too.

Comment: When you say "not working in Firefox" do you mean "works in all the browsers I've tried except Firefox" or "I've only tested in Firefox and it doesn't work"?

Comment: @Derek image maps are not ancient at all, they just aren't used that often; they have a specialized purpose.

Comment: +1 for no jQuery, But do add some more information, like an example of the problem on [JSBin](http://jsbin.com) or JSFiddle

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the page you are using this on is: http://britobmarketing.com/

---

Your problem seems to be with how you are defining your imagemap; not how the javascript is working

Your imagemap setup:

```
<map name="mainMap">
    <a rel="thumbnail" href="images/contactUsPic.jpg">
        <area onmouseout="document.pic1.src='images/mapPics.gif'" onmouseover="document.pic1.src='images/contactUs.gif'" title="Contact Us" shape="rect" coords="798,481,877,572">
    </a>
    <area target="_blank" href="http://www.facebook.com/britoBMarketing" title="Facebook" shape="rect" coords="884,298,956,357">
</map>
```

Playing around with Firebug's "inspect element", it seems that stripping out the `target` and `title` attributes seems to remove the problem.

Also your main `<area/>`s are wrapped with anchors (`<a>`) which is probably preventing them from working.

Try something like this:

```
<map name="mainMap">
 <area coords="191,138,487,233" shape="rect" href="" onmouseover="alert('hello')">
</map>
```

Comment: yes, in my dreamweaver it marks the <a> tags around the area in black which indicates a problem but... how do I get it to rely on the JS inside the area tag? I used the <a> because there i can use the rel attribute and make it rely on the JS code so when the image is clicked it opens on a thumbnail...